# DRV8825 with ESP32 new PCB not moving stepper motors at all, help troubleshooting or seeing the problem with the design

Tags: esp32, stepper-driver

[image]

Program

```
const int stepPinX = 2;

const int stepPinY = 18;

const int  DAC_CH2 = 26; // blue



void setup()
{
  pinMode(stepPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(stepPinY, OUTPUT);


  //  dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 150);      // 2 V

}

void loop()
{
  //  stepX();
  for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
  {
    dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 50);
    stepY();
    stepX();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
  {
    dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 150);
    stepY();
    stepX();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
  {
    dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 200);
    stepY();
    stepX();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++)
  {
    dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 255);
    stepY();
    stepX();
  }   

  delay(1000);
}


void stepX()
{
  digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(50);
  digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(800);
}
void stepY()
{
  digitalWrite(stepPinY, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(50);
  digitalWrite(stepPinY, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(800);
}
```

Note - just trying to get either X or Y axis working (not Z).

PCB

[image]

There is a large heat sink on top of the driver ICs.

[image]

(The heat sink jumper just connects the top pad to the bottom pad of the driver.)

A previous version of this PCB works. Although, it is not tied to a schematic. So that's why I am trying to get this one to work. Any suggestions or anything you see that should probably be changed?

- Continuity test of all traces between DRV8825s and ESP32
- Voltage measurements at logic high points Without 24V power (just ESP32) With
- 24V power Cut between pin 1 and 2. Does not run. No sound, nothing.
- Cut trace before 1&2. Nothing. No change from changed DAC (pin 1&2
  voltage) to

  - 0.6 V (50)
  - 1.3 V (100)
  - 1.9 V (150)
  - 2.6 V (200)
  - 3v3 (255)
- Put on 24 to 5V regulator. Made loud tone. Changed step delay and the same resulted: 500, 1000, 1200, 1500,
  2000, 2500 (us).
- Put 33kΩ between ground and pin 1&2. No change.
- Tried incrementing step delay.

Comment: I hope there is a separate GND layer, that I just don't see. It is hard to find layout problems with this image resolution, there are many very narrow zones, especially below the driver chips. Did you run a design rule check?

Comment: Yes, ran DRC in Eagle. No ground layer